# RecyclerView giving errors

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi i am new to android project so i am trying to use recycler view. but it is not working. i keep getting errors @ this line " RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, getData());" it says RecyclerAdapter (android.content.context, List) in RecyclerAdapter cannot be applied to my package class please help

```
statement.java


import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import nnnnn.R;
import nnnnnn.RecyclerAdapter;
import nnnnnnnnnnnnn.Landscape;




public class Statements extends Fragment {
    Toolbar toolbar;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.statements,container,false);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) v.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Statements");
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main);

        setUpRecyclerView();
        return v;}

    private void setUpRecyclerView() {


        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        RecyclerAdapter adapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this.getActivity(),Landscape.getData());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

       final LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManagerVertical = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getActivity()); // (Context context, int spanCount)
        mLinearLayoutManagerVertical.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManagerVertical);

        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator()); // Even if we dont use it then also our items shows default animation. #Check Docs
    }




}
```

RecyclerAdapter code is below

```
 RecyclerAdapter
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

import xx.xx.xx.xx.xx.R;
import xx.xx.xx.xx.model.Landscape;


public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private static final String TAG = RecyclerAdapter.class.getSimpleName();

    private List<Landscape> mDataList;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Landscape> data) {
        this.mDataList = data;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }



    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreateViewHolder");

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.statementlist, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onBindViewHolder" + position);

        Landscape current = mDataList.get(position);
        holder.setData(current, position);
        holder.setListeners();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataList.size();
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        mDataList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
//      notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mDataList.size());
//      notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addItem(int position, Landscape landscape) {
        mDataList.add(position, landscape);
        notifyItemInserted(position);
//      notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mDataList.size());
//      notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView title;
        ImageView imgThumb, imgDelete, imgAdd;
        int position;
        Landscape current;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            title       = (TextView)  itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
            imgThumb    = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_row);
            imgDelete   = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_row_delete);
            imgAdd      = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_row_add);
        }

        public void setData(Landscape current, int position) {
            this.title.setText(current.getTitle());
            imgThumb.setImageResource(current.getImageID());
            this.position = position;
            this.current = current;
        }

        public void setListeners() {
            imgDelete.setOnClickListener(MyViewHolder.this);
            imgAdd.setOnClickListener(MyViewHolder.this);
            imgThumb.setOnClickListener(MyViewHolder.this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
//          Log.i("onClick before operation", position + " " + mDataList.size());
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.img_row_delete:
                    removeItem(position);
                    break;

                case R.id.img_row_add:
                    addItem(position, current);
                    break;
            }
//          Log.i("onClick after operation", mDataList.size() + " \n\n" + mDataList.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're passing in "this" for the first argument to RecyclerAdapter.  "this" being a Fragment class.  The Fragment class does not extend from Context, so it cannot be used as such.

Try "this.getActivity()".  This may result in null, so ideally put this within the Fragment subclass's "onActivityCreated" method (instead of the "onCreateView" method)

Comment: thanks @fishstix now after running the app it crashes this is the error given "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference"

Comment: Seems you also have a bug here: recyclerView = (RecyclerView) recyclerView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);  (you should just be calling findViewById() on the Fragment class... not on the currently null recyclerview instance)

Comment: yeah when i remove the recyclerView.findViewByid i get an error showing cannot resolve method

Comment: As you're editing the code, it's hard to follow what you may or may not be doing right and wrong.  Without seeing the updated code as well as updated stack traces, this will be difficult to solve.  It seems your primary issue with the recyclerview may be solved, and now there is an issue navigating views within the fragment environment.  Eitherway, more information is needed.

Comment: okay i edited the code above to what i have now you can chcek it out

Answer (score 0):

You need to override `OnActivitycreated` in order to call getActivity. Call setUpRecyclerView in OnActivitycreated and add `getActivity.` before `findViewById` and it will work